# Running a statement after closing JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I created my main JFrame and added a button with click event that will show my JDialog named AddProductGUI.

```
AddProductGUI addProductGUI = new AddProductGUI();
addProductGUI.AddNewProduct();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "message");
```

My code for AddNewProduct(), my constructor just position each component.

```
public void AddNewProduct() {
        addProductGUI = new AddProductGUI();
        addProductGUI.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        addProductGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        addProductGUI.txtProductID.setText("");
        addProductGUI.txtCode.setText("");
        addProductGUI.txtName.setText("");
        addProductGUI.txtBrand.setText("");
        addProductGUI.setVisible(true);
}
```

AddNewProduct() method simply just shows the JDialog and sets the textfields without text. My problem is when my AddProductGUI appears the my message dialog also appear. How can I make my message dialog appear only after closing JDialog?

Comment: What code is in the AddNewProduct() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your `AddProductGUI` extends `JDialog` . Then take a look to constructor from `JDialog` you have to set `modal` `true`. [JDialog api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html). By the way in java by convention method's name starts with lower-case.